# What is the height of oil in this U-tube?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, density

First, we added water till it reached **A** level. After we added oil, water level decreased by **2.4 cm** (**B** level). What is the height of oil if water has density of **1000 kg/$m^3$** and oil has density of **800 kg/$m^3$**
[image]

Comment: How do the pressures on the two sides of the Utube compare at level B?  If the water level on the right side has dropped 2.4 cm, how far above level B has the water on the left side risen?

Comment: that is part of the questions

Comment: Where in the problem statement you presented is this found?

Comment: The weight of the volume of water  (height times area (2_pi_1^2) times density) ) on the left side that is above the A-line is the same as the weight of the oil (height times area 2_pi_2^2 times density) above the A-line on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The water on the right dropped 2.4 cm below the A level so, to conserve mass, the water on the left had to rise 2(2.4)=4.8 cm above the A level (because the area on the right side is 2 times the area on the left).  So the water on the left in the final picture is 4.8 + 2.4 = 7.2 cm above the B level.  Since the pressures on the two sides of the U have to be the same at the B level (there is all water below this level in the U), we must have at the B level:
$$p_B=\rho_{water}g (7.2)=\rho_{oil}g h_{oil}$$
So, $$h_{oil}=\frac{1.0}{0.8}(7.2)=9\ cm$$

Comment: Did you use the numbers above the tube as radii ?

Comment: If so, should it be only 9.6 cm above B level ?

Comment: Oops.  I read them as cm, rather than cm^2.  I will go back and correct that.  Thanks for spotting it.